# How to put a link on a button with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, hyperlink

How would one put a link on a button with bootstrap?

there are 4 methods in the bootstrap documentation:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Input Button">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button">
```

The first one doesn't work for me, no button shows, just the text with the link, have a feeling its the theme im using.

The second one shows the button which is what i want, but whats the code make the button link to another page when clicked?

Cheers

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lstcymqo/ the problem may be with the theme you are using

Comment: [What are the differences between buttons and links?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/5493)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can call a function on click event of button.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Input Button" onclick=" relocate_home()">

<script>
function relocate_home()
{
     location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
} 
</script>
```

OR 
Use this Code

```
<a href="#link" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
```

Comment: Quite a bad accepted answer : how your links are parsed by web crawlers ? No title, no target, that's not a link, that's a redirection ...

Comment: This is totally unnecessary and really bad for SEO. Have a look at my solution below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44130105/1202214).

Comment: second option is off the question. I never tried the js code though  but this might limit the developer and make him write more codes when he has a lot of buttons to use at different places.

Answer (score 226):

The easiest solution is the first one of your examples:

```
<a href="#link" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
```

The reason it's not working for you is most likely, as you say, a problem in the theme you're using. There is no reason to resort to bloated extra markup or inline Javascript for this.

Comment: And where would I put the target?

Comment: This works. It is not large enough, just add **btn-lg** to the class as: **class="btn btn-info btn-lg"**

Comment: I have similar problem in bootstrap 4.6 and this is what I want to use just like he asked in the question above
<button class="btn float-right hidden-sm-down btn-success"><i class="mdi mdi-check-circle"></i> Run Payment</button>

Answer (score 143):

If you don't really need the button element, just move the classes to a regular link:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="/save/1" class="btn btn-primary active">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save
    </a>
    <a href="/cancel/1" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Conversely, you can also change a button to appear like a link:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

Comment: a much better answer than the accepted one - no need for javascript.. thanks

Comment: Be aware of semantically and for accessibility when you should use a button and when you should use a link. Generally, button for actions on the page, and links for content in the page or to navigate away from the page.

Comment: Second option works but you didn't put the code block out well

Answer (score 20):

Another trick to get the link color working correctly inside the `<button>` markup

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success and-all-other-classes"> 
  <a href="#" style="color:inherit"> Button text with correct colors </a>
</button>
```

Please keep in mind that in bs4 beta e.g. `btn-primary-outline` changed to `btn-outline-primary`

Comment: This is the easiest and most flexible form and semantics that should be applied here. 
Thanks for your response.
This meets the needs of my search as well as the question being asked.

Answer (score 15):

This is how I solved

```
   <a href="#" >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button Text</button>
   </a>
```

Comment: If this works I still think it doesn't answer the question following the requirement of the main post.

Answer (score 9):

Combining the above answers i find a simply solution that probably will help you too:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="location.href = 'your_link';">Login</button>
```

by just adding inline JS code you can transform a button in a link and keeping his design.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the anchor tag as a button. Change the role to type as below in bootstrap 5.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="#">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just simply add the following code;

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://localhost:8080/Home" role="button">Home Page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking with Bootstrap, the best option in my opinion is to choose the class [btn-link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#:%7E:text=%3Cbutton%20type%3D%22button%22%20class%3D%22btn%20btn%2Dlink%22%3ELink%3C/button%3E%5D).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

If you want the btn-link to send you to another page or activate something such as a modal, you can include the onClick like others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
  <a href='#' className='text-decoration-none'>
    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-5 d-flex justify-content-center" type='submit'>Sign In</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easiest and clean approach is (without any extra javascript functions):

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
   <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
</a>
```

To use fontawesome icons, you can just put the following link in your header:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And that's all

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the button element, a nice trick that I found to make it work looks like this:

- Create a data attribute with the url that you want to redirect
- Attach an event listener to fetch the url from the data attribute on element
- Open the url using window.open or your preferred method

**Html file**

```
<button type="button" id="newpagebutton" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ml-3">Open new page</button>
```

**Javascript file**

```
$( "#newpagebutton" ).attr('data-buttonlink', 'https://www.apple.com')


$( "#newpagebutton" ).click(function() {
  const buttonlink = $("#newpagebutton").data('buttonlink')

  window.open(buttonlink)
});
```

Have a look at how the implementation works on [fiddle.js](https://jsfiddle.net/jcassio/21nb8gd3/12/#&togetherjs=Ruwb2K4aRv)