# How to display a link as a Bootstrap basic button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The basic button class ("btn") is displayed in 'a' tag in other way as in 'button' tag:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" role="button">Link Button</a>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
```

[image: Bootstrap button in a tag and in button tag]

Other button classes ("btn btn-default", "btn btn-primary", ...) are displayed in both tags identical, see: https://jsfiddle.net/antoninslejska/9gps82da/3/

I can use inline Javascript, see: [How to put a link on a button with bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36003670/3886962):

```
<button onclick="location.href = '#my-link';" class="btn">Link Button</button>
```

But I do not find this approach as optimal. Is there some other way, how to display a link as a Bootstrap basic button?

Comment: Do you want to show internal pages link onClick? so add this code onclick="window.location.href='students.html';"

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here. Your title suggest you want to render an `a` tag as a Bootstrap styled button, but your fiddle demonstrates that. Can you clarify?

Comment: The fiddle demonstrates, that the basic button (class="btn") works differently as other button types (class="btn btn-default", ...). See the first two buttons in the fiddle.

Comment: But you never use `btn` on it's own, that's not valid Bootstrap code.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-buttons.php

Comment: In Bootstrap Docs is not the basic (gray) button stated: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons-options

Comment: First, never ever use *w3schools*, they are awful. Second, use the official docs - on there you will not see the `btn` class used without a `btn-*`. Inspect the button on the official docs, you will see it there too.

Comment: I can use other colours, but the problem is that the gray button looks in my design much better as the other colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap button classes always come in pairs.

1. The `btn` class is used to set up how it looks. So things like padding, alignment, border radius.
2. The secondary classes are for setting the colours. For example `btn-primary` sets the background and border colour to be blue and the text to be white.

So it seems that you want a gray button. The easiest way to do that would be to define your own secondary class. For example, add this to your CSS:

```
.btn-mybutton {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Now you can create your own buttons like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-mybutton" role="button">Link Button</a>
```

For example:

```css
.btn-mybutton {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-mybutton" role="button">Link Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I use: .btn-gray { color: inherit; background-color: #F0F0F0; }

Comment: Minor point, but I hate naming CSS classes after the things they contain. Let's say your styling changes and you want your gray buttons to be blue, now your CSS name looks very silly!

Comment: :-) It's just an examle. I never copy real code to a public website, unless it is open source.

Comment: Example and proof-of-concept code has a habit of becoming "real" code. Better to get in a good habit and do it right in the first place :)